# Filezilla Server - AUTH TLS timeout and Server sent unsorted certificate chain in violation of the TLS specifications problems

Tags: ssl, ftp

I have Filezilla Server (0.9.6 beta) setup on a Windows 2008R2 server. Until recently it was running fine but lately, we've been receiving reports of connection errors.

The two most common reports are
1. Connection timeout after the AUTH TLS command
2. Server sent unsorted certificate chain in violation of the TLS specifications

When connecting with Filezilla FTP client (3.45.1), I get both errors but randomly. Sometimes the first error appears and other times the second error appears.

Using https://ftptest.net, I was able to reproduce the errors on a consistent basis.

**Using Explicit TLS over FTP**:

```
Status: Connecting to xx.xx.xxx.xx  
Warning: The entered address does not resolve to an IPv6 address.  
Status: Connected, waiting for welcome message...  
Reply: 220 Welcome to FTP server.  
Command: CLNT https://ftptest.net on behalf of xx.xx.xxx.xx  
Reply: 200 Don't care  
Command: AUTH TLS  
Error: Connection timed out
```

**Using Implicit TLS over FTP**:

```
Status: Resolving address of ftp.xxxxxx.com  
Status: Connecting to xx.xx.xxx.xx  
Warning: The entered address does not resolve to an IPv6 address.  
Status: Connected, performing TLS handshake...  
Error: TLS handshake failed: An unexpected TLS packet was received.
```

**Using Allow fallback to plain FTP**:

```
Status: Resolving address of ftp.xxxxxx.com  
Status: Connecting to xx.xx.xxx.xx  
Warning: The entered address does not resolve to an IPv6 address.  
Status: Connected, waiting for welcome message...  
Reply: 220 Welcome to FTP server.  
Command: CLNT https://ftptest.net on behalf of xx.xx.xxx.xx  
Reply: 200 Don't care  
Command: AUTH TLS  
Reply: 234 Using authentication type TLS  
Status: Performing TLS handshake...  
Status: TLS handshake successful, verifying certificate...  
Status: Received 4 certificates from server.  
Status: cert[0]: subject='OU=Domain Control Validated,OU=COMODO SSL Wildcard,CN=*.xxxxxx.com' issuer='C=GB,ST=Greater Manchester,L=Salford,O=Sectigo Limited,CN=Sectigo RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA'  
Status: cert[1]: subject='C=SE,O=AddTrust AB,OU=AddTrust External TTP Network,CN=AddTrust External CA Root' issuer='C=SE,O=AddTrust AB,OU=AddTrust External TTP Network,CN=AddTrust External CA Root'  
Status: cert[2]: subject='C=US,ST=New Jersey,L=Jersey City,O=The USERTRUST Network,CN=USERTrust RSA Certification Authority' issuer='C=SE,O=AddTrust AB,OU=AddTrust External TTP Network,CN=AddTrust External CA Root'  
Status: cert[3]: subject='C=GB,ST=Greater Manchester,L=Salford,O=Sectigo Limited,CN=Sectigo RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA' issuer='C=US,ST=New Jersey,L=Jersey City,O=The USERTRUST Network,CN=USERTrust RSA Certification Authority'  
Error: Peer certificate chain received in wrong order. The TLS specifications require that each certificate in the chain must directly certify the one preceeding it.
```

When I try using openssl to connect, no certificates are sent:

```
openssl s_client -starttls ftp -connect ftp.xxxxxx.com:21
CONNECTED(000001A8)
write:errno=0
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 43 bytes and written 329 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

### Questions

For Plain FTP, I'm struggling to read the certificate order to determine what is wrong. even if I work that out, there doesn't appear to be a way to change that order in Filezilla server. What should I be looking at here?

For explicit TLS, I don't know why the AUTH TLS command keeps timing out. Could it be because of the certificate order as well?

The plain FTP connection will give an error but will still continue with the directory listing. However, the explicit TLS connection won't move past the AUTH TLS error. Would fixing the explicit TLS connection error also solve the certificate ordering error?